# $(this) limitation outside of scope to target specified element

Tags: jquery

if you want to delete a specified li in a ul, u simply do this

```
$('ul').on('click',function(){
    $(this).find('li').remove();
});
```

but for my case, I'm selecting a submit button of a dialog box.. I can't use $(this), either direct select my li, because it will remove all..

```
$('#submit).click(function(){
   //delete one of my target li..
});
```

Comment: Can't you just be more specific with the selector? eg you can use the class name or ID of the targeted `<li>` element?

Comment: @Terry my element is dynamic, if i select them even using id or class or name, they are gone entirely

Comment: Please show a *complete* example of what you're trying to do, including the HTML. It's not clear what is the criteria for which element exactly you want to remove.

Comment: No they aren't gone entirely. Why would they be gone if they are displayed on your page? I don't get your problem.

Comment: Can you be more specific on how you want to be able to select a specific "li" for deletion by using just one button?

Comment: @LloydBanks I'm using bootstrap modal aka a dialog to confirm before delete the item (aka a <li>)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this two-step process with the following JavaScript code

```
$('li').on('click',function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#c" + id).show();
});

$(".confirm").on("click", function(){
    var id = ($(this).attr("id")).substring(1, 2);
    $("#" + id).remove();
});
```

[Working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/nyWMJ/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm Not sure with your DOM structure. This will work when you want to remove the list items of a list when a submit button is clicked.

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
   $('#Id_of_Your_list').find('li').remove();
});
```

I can give a perfect solution if you be specific with the requirement.

**EDIT**

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
   $( this ).parent( "li" ).remove();
});
```

Will work for your case.

Comment: @KaitlynSacco You haven't told us what you want to remove instead. The first li? The last? The third? The one that contains a picture of a kitten?

Comment: the li which user click on the delete btn, which the delete btn is within the li, but the problem is now im using a dialog box..

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this,

```
<ul onclick="remove(this)"><li></li></ul>
```

In `remove()`

```
function remove(this) {
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
}
```

Comment: yup, the problem is my click button is at a submit button of a dialog box.. too far to traverse that way

Comment: Do you want the form to not to be submitted?

Answer (score 0):

How do you select the target? You should add a css class to mark the list item as selected. So the selected `li` has the mark-up `<li class="selected">` after selection.

Then do the following in your handler

```
 $('#submit).click(function(){  
    var deleteThis = $('li .selected'); 

    //Do the deletion
   }
```

Comment: You need to do $(deleteThis)[0].remove() perhaps.